# Extracting specific text from a column when its position keeps on changing

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Sample data]

The sample data can be created with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AddonName': ['Size: Medium<br />Addon: Grey textured organza top [+$224.00]',
               'Addon: Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]<br '
               '/>Addon: Straight silk pants [+$94.40]<br />Size: Large',
               'Size: Medium<br />Addon: Detailed cotton pants [+$36.00]',
               'Size: Large<br />Addon: Cotton khadi shalwar [+$36.00]',
               'Size: M/LARGE<br />Addon: Straight cotton detailed pants '
               '[+$34.00]',
               'Addon: Cotton net lehnga [+$480.00]<br />Size: M/Large',
               'Size: Large<br />Addon: Cotton net detailed dupatta with '
               'emboss and screen print [+PKR 15,500]',
               'Size: Custom Order<br />Addon: Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR '
               '13,500]<br />Addon: Chiffon Chann work dupatta [+PKR 22,000]',
               'Size: Custom Order<br />Addon: Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR '
               '13,500]<br />Addon: Chiffon textured dupatta [+PKR 24,650]',
               'Addon: Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]<br '
               '/>Addon: Straight silk pants [+$94.40]<br />Size: M/Large',
               'Addon: Crepe silk shalwar [+&#163;58.56]<br />Size: M/LARGE',
               'Size: Medium'],
 'AddonTotal': [31584.0,
                29666.4,
                5076.0,
                5076.0,
                4794.0,
                67680.0,
                23124.0,
                62604.0,
                65593.2,
                29666.4,
                10716.0,
                0.0],
 'LineItemCategory': ['Luxury Pret,Traditional',
                      'Luxury Pret,Traditional',
                      'Basic Pret,New Arrivals',
                      'Basic Pret,Eid Collection,New Arrivals',
                      'Basic Pret',
                      'Formal,Heavy',
                      'Formal,Heavy',
                      'Formal,Heavy',
                      'Formal,Heavy',
                      'Luxury Pret,Traditional',
                      'Luxury Pret,Traditional',
                      'Basic Pret,New Arrivals'],
 'LineItemQty': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]},
    columns=['LineItemQty', 'LineItemCategory', 'AddonName', 'AddonTotal'])
```

So i have a very large dataset. kindly have a look at sample data. In column name *AddonName* i need to extract two different thing into separate columns. First i need the size and secondly i need the Addon with their descriptions.
Here is what i tried:

```
sep=df['AddonName'].str.split("<")
```

Adding the seperated values to new column i.e AddonSize

```
df['AddonSize']=sep.str[0]
sepq=df['AddonSize'].str.split(":")
```

Seperation by symbol

```
sep1=df['AddonName'].str.split(">", expand=False)
df['AddonSize']=sepq.str[1]
```

Adding the seperated values to new column

```
df['AddonDetail1']=sep1.str[1:]
```

When extracting the data position wise all of this works fine only when the position of *size* and *addon* details are the same.
But if you look at the sample data, the position of *size* keeps on changing in the cell. sometimes it comes at the start of the text and sometimes at the end. As the dateset is big i cannot do it manually.
Kindly help me do it.
Thanks

Comment: If you had provided the sample data in copyable text, I could have tested a regex against it. Because I am way too lazy to re-type the full sample... So unless you edit your post with a [mcve] *including copyable input data*, I can only give you this hint: regexes could help here.

Comment: Hi sorry about that. i have added the link to data file

Comment: Avoid links because they can become broken, but copy the data in the question itself (I have done it for you this time).

Comment: oh i get it. Thanks alot man:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use regex. The code is following:

```
>>> df['size'] = df.AddonName.str.extract(r'(Size: )+([\w\s\/]+)')[1]
>>> print(df['size'])
0           Medium
1            Large
2           Medium
3            Large
4          M/LARGE
5          M/Large
6            Large
7     Custom Order
8     Custom Order
9          M/Large
10         M/LARGE
11          Medium
```

To extract `Addon`, just replace `Size:` with `Addon:`:

```
>>> df['addon'] = df.AddonName.str.extract(r'(Addon: )+([\w\s\/]+)')[1]
>>> print(df['addon'])
0                            Grey textured organza top 
1            Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print 
2                                Detailed cotton pants 
3                                 Cotton khadi shalwar 
4                       Straight cotton detailed pants 
5                                    Cotton net lehnga 
6     Cotton net detailed dupatta with emboss and sc...
7                               Plain Silk Izaar pants 
8                               Plain Silk Izaar pants 
9            Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print 
10                                  Crepe silk shalwar 
11                                                  NaN
```

Comment: just one more thing,for addon extraction this code is only extracting the first instance of addone. however in many case i have musltiple addons in one row, how do extract all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas allow to directly extract regexes from text columns. Here you can get the sizes with:

```
df.AddonName.str.extract(r'Size:\s*(\w+)')
```

which gives

```
         0
0   Medium
1    Large
2   Medium
3    Large
4        M
5        M
6    Large
7   Custom
8   Custom
9        M
10       M
11  Medium
```

And you can get the addons with:

```
df.AddonName.str.extract(r'Addon:\s*(.*?\])')
```

which gives:

```
                                                                         0
0                                     Grey textured organza top [+$224.00]
1                     Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]
2                                          Detailed cotton pants [+$36.00]
3                                           Cotton khadi shalwar [+$36.00]
4                                 Straight cotton detailed pants [+$34.00]
5                                             Cotton net lehnga [+$480.00]
6   Cotton net detailed dupatta with emboss and screen print [+PKR 15,500]
7                                     Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]
8                                     Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]
9                     Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]
10                                       Crepe silk shalwar [+&#163;58.56]
11                                                                     NaN
```

---

Above code only give the first addon. If you want all of them, each on a row, you must use `extractall` instead of `extract`:

```
df.AddonName.str.extractall(r'Addon:\s*(.*?\])').reset_index(
    level=1, drop=True).rename(columns=lambda x: 'Addon')
```

giving:

```
                                                Addon
0                Grey textured organza top [+$224.00]
1   Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$1...
1                       Straight silk pants [+$94.40]
2                     Detailed cotton pants [+$36.00]
3                      Cotton khadi shalwar [+$36.00]
4            Straight cotton detailed pants [+$34.00]
5                        Cotton net lehnga [+$480.00]
6   Cotton net detailed dupatta with emboss and sc...
7                Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]
7            Chiffon Chann work dupatta [+PKR 22,000]
8                Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]
8              Chiffon textured dupatta [+PKR 24,650]
9   Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$1...
9                       Straight silk pants [+$94.40]
10                  Crepe silk shalwar [+&#163;58.56]
```

But as you may have more than one row for a given index, you must use `join` if you want to add the new column to the original dataframe:

```
df.join(df.AddonName.str.extractall(r'Addon:\s*(.*?\])').reset_index(
    level=1, drop=True))
```

giving:

```
    LineItemQty                        LineItemCategory                                                                                                                 AddonName  AddonTotal                                                                       0
0             1                 Luxury Pret,Traditional                                                             Size: Medium<br />Addon: Grey textured organza top [+$224.00]     31584.0                                    Grey textured organza top [+$224.00]
1             1                 Luxury Pret,Traditional    Addon: Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]<br />Addon: Straight silk pants [+$94.40]<br />Size: Large     29666.4                    Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]
1             1                 Luxury Pret,Traditional    Addon: Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]<br />Addon: Straight silk pants [+$94.40]<br />Size: Large     29666.4                                           Straight silk pants [+$94.40]
2             1                 Basic Pret,New Arrivals                                                                  Size: Medium<br />Addon: Detailed cotton pants [+$36.00]      5076.0                                         Detailed cotton pants [+$36.00]
3             1  Basic Pret,Eid Collection,New Arrivals                                                                    Size: Large<br />Addon: Cotton khadi shalwar [+$36.00]      5076.0                                          Cotton khadi shalwar [+$36.00]
4             1                              Basic Pret                                                        Size: M/LARGE<br />Addon: Straight cotton detailed pants [+$34.00]      4794.0                                Straight cotton detailed pants [+$34.00]
5             1                            Formal,Heavy                                                                    Addon: Cotton net lehnga [+$480.00]<br />Size: M/Large     67680.0                                            Cotton net lehnga [+$480.00]
6             1                            Formal,Heavy                            Size: Large<br />Addon: Cotton net detailed dupatta with emboss and screen print [+PKR 15,500]     23124.0  Cotton net detailed dupatta with emboss and screen print [+PKR 15,500]
7             1                            Formal,Heavy  Size: Custom Order<br />Addon: Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]<br />Addon: Chiffon Chann work dupatta [+PKR 22,000]     62604.0                                    Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]
7             1                            Formal,Heavy  Size: Custom Order<br />Addon: Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]<br />Addon: Chiffon Chann work dupatta [+PKR 22,000]     62604.0                                Chiffon Chann work dupatta [+PKR 22,000]
8             1                            Formal,Heavy    Size: Custom Order<br />Addon: Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]<br />Addon: Chiffon textured dupatta [+PKR 24,650]     65593.2                                    Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]
8             1                            Formal,Heavy    Size: Custom Order<br />Addon: Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500]<br />Addon: Chiffon textured dupatta [+PKR 24,650]     65593.2                                  Chiffon textured dupatta [+PKR 24,650]
9             1                 Luxury Pret,Traditional  Addon: Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]<br />Addon: Straight silk pants [+$94.40]<br />Size: M/Large     29666.4                    Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]
9             1                 Luxury Pret,Traditional  Addon: Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00]<br />Addon: Straight silk pants [+$94.40]<br />Size: M/Large     29666.4                                           Straight silk pants [+$94.40]
10            1                 Luxury Pret,Traditional                                                               Addon: Crepe silk shalwar [+&#163;58.56]<br />Size: M/LARGE     10716.0                                       Crepe silk shalwar [+&#163;58.56]
11            1                 Basic Pret,New Arrivals                                                                                                              Size: Medium         0.0                                                                     NaN
```

You could also join the different addons on one single row with a separator (here a comma):

```
df.AddonName.str.extractall(r'Addon:\s*(.*?\])').groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

giving:

```
                                                                                     0
0                                                 Grey textured organza top [+$224.00]
1   Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00],Straight silk pants [+$94.40]
2                                                      Detailed cotton pants [+$36.00]
3                                                       Cotton khadi shalwar [+$36.00]
4                                             Straight cotton detailed pants [+$34.00]
5                                                         Cotton net lehnga [+$480.00]
6               Cotton net detailed dupatta with emboss and screen print [+PKR 15,500]
7        Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500],Chiffon Chann work dupatta [+PKR 22,000]
8          Plain Silk Izaar pants [+PKR 13,500],Chiffon textured dupatta [+PKR 24,650]
9   Cotton net dupatta with gold screen print [+$116.00],Straight silk pants [+$94.40]
10                                                   Crepe silk shalwar [+&#163;58.56]
```

Comment: just one more thing,for addon extraction this code is only extracting the first instance of addone. however in many case i have musltiple addons in one row, how do extract all of them?

Comment: @Sarfraz: could you give an example of the expected result when there are more that one addon?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame( {'AddonName':[ Size: King [+PKR 940]<br />Addons: Duvet Set (3 pcs) [+PKR 7,890]<br />Addons: Sheet Set (3 pcs) [+PKR  4,610]<br />Addons: Square Cushion Pair (2 Pcs) [+PKR 800]<br />Addons: Euro Sham Pair (2 Pcs) [+PKR 1,500]<br />Addons: Dec Pillow Pair (2 pcs) [+PKR 1,000]

Comment: Or this is the value of one row:
Size: King [+PKR 940]<br />Addons: Duvet Set (3 pcs) [+PKR 7,890]<br />Addons: Sheet Set (3 pcs) [+PKR  4,610]<br />Addons: Square Cushion Pair (2 Pcs) [+PKR 800]<br />Addons: Euro Sham Pair (2 Pcs) [+PKR 1,500]<br />Addons: Dec Pillow Pair (2 pcs) [+PKR 1,000]

Comment: @Sarfraz: My question was about the expected result. Do you want a list, the concatenated addon strings, with a separator between them?

Comment: i need each of addon with its details in a single row. the concatenated addon strings, with a separator between each of them is fine

Comment: Thats great. You are a life saver. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Although I am a big fan of regex as well, I try to avoid them if I can solve a problem using only "classic" string functions. I do this for two main reasons: regex might be harder to read and also they might be slower.

So, for the sake of providing an alternative solution that doesn't use the regex, here it is my example.
Besides not using regex, my example also deals with the situation when there are two Addon values on the same row (see the rows 2, 8, 9, 10)

```py
for row in df['AddonName']:
    # prepare a dictionary for each row
    dict_data = {
        # Size is a single value
        'Size': None,
        # Addon is a list because there might be more than one Addon on each row
        'Addon': []
    }
    for sep in row.split('<br />'):
        # split the row by <br />. Each separated value will either start with Size: or Addon:
        if sep.startswith('Size:'):
            # len('Size:') is 5 so slice the sep and take everything after 'Size:'
            dict_data['Size'] = sep[5:].strip()
        elif sep.startswith('Addon:'):
            # len('Addon:') is 6 so slice the sep and take everything after 'Size:' then append it to the list
            dict_data['Addon'].append(sep[6:].strip())
    # do whatever you need with dict_data, like adding it to some new column into the dataframe
    print(dict_data)
```

You may completely skip the creation of the dict_data dictionary and directly insert the extracted values for Size and Addon to some new column into the dataframe. I only chose this approach to easily demonstrate the solution.